# como puedo hacer que un boton ejecute 2 funciones ala vez una después de la otra?

Tags: php, funciones

tengo 2 botones uno realiza un submit ingresa datos a una base de datos y el otro guarda una captura de pantalla de un div, me gustaría que el que realiza el submit ejecute primero la función de captura de pantalla y luego guarde el formulario,
el usuario pone sus datos da al botón guardar este toma la captura y luego guarda los datos eso e gustaría hacer, gracias por su ayuda ocupo que todo este en el index,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>prueba</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="Hotspot Auth Page">
        <meta name="revised" content="fyang, 2014/4/11/" />
        <meta name="author" content="fyang">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>

<script src="html2canvas.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudpe=flare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-108924172-1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="html2canvas.js"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-108924172-1');
</script>


        <!--<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">-->

        <style type="text/css">
            body {
                font-family: "Microsoft YaHei", "Trebuchet MS", "Myriad Pro", Arial, sans-serif;
                color: #000;
                margin:0;
                background-color:#fff;
            }

            .header{
                width: 100%;
                height: 45px;
                background-color: #000;
                padding-right: 0;
                padding-left: 0;
                text-align: center;
                display: table;
            }

            .header span{
                display: table-cell;
                width: 100%;
                height:100%;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 18px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            .footer{
                margin-top: 260px;
                display: table;
                width: 100%;
                height: 45px;
                background-color: #000;
                padding-right: 0;
                padding-left: 0;
                text-align: center;
            }

            .footer p{
                display: table-cell;
                width: 100%;
                height:100%;
                color: #fff;
                font-size: 16px;
                vertical-align: middle;
            }

            #powerby{
                font-style: italic;
            }


     .top-img{
    weight:300px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:blue;

     }

    .login{
        left:17px;
     position:absolute;
     top:300px;

    width:100%;
     text-align: center;
     }

     .btn-primary:active:hover,
     .btn-primary.active:hover,
     .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:hover,
     .btn-primary:active:focus,
     .btn-primary.active:focus,
     .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary:focus,
     .btn-primary:active.focus,
     .btn-primary.active.focus,
     .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary.focus {
     color: #fff;
      background-color: #204d74;
     border-color: #122b40;
     }
     .btn-primary:active,
     .btn-primary.active,
     .open > .dropdown-toggle.btn-primary {
      background-image: none;
     }
     .btn-primary.disabled:hover,
     .btn-primary[disabled]:hover,
     fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:hover,
     .btn-primary.disabled:focus,
     .btn-primary[disabled]:focus,
     fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary:focus,
     .btn-primary.disabled.focus,
     .btn-primary[disabled].focus,
     fieldset[disabled] .btn-primary.focus {
      background-color: #337ab7;
      border-color: #2e6da4;
     }
     .btn-primary .badge {
      color: #337ab7;
      background-color: #fff;
     }

     .formulario{
     position:absolute;

     }

      </style>
       <script>
      var cuenta=0;
      function enviado() {
      if (cuenta == 0) {
       cuenta++;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
         }
     </script>



     <?php

     $conn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","prueba");
     $resultado = "";
     $nombre=@$_POST["nombre"];
     $cedula=@$_POST["cedula"];
     $telefono=@$_POST["telefono"];
     if (isset ($_POST['submit'])){


         $strSQL = "INSERT into datosUsuario(nombre,cedula,telefono) values                                         
     ('$nombre','$cedula','$telefono')";
    $query = mysqli_query($conn, $strSQL);
    if($query){
      $resultado = "exitoso";
    }else{
      $resultado = "error";
            }
        }

        ?>

        <script>

        function valida(e){
            tecla = (document.all) ? e.keyCode : e.which;

    //Tecla de retroceso para borrar, siempre la permite
    if (tecla==8){
        return true;
    }

    // Patron de entrada, en este caso solo acepta numeros
    patron =/[0-9]/;

    tecla_final = String.fromCharCode(tecla);
    return patron.test(tecla_final);
        }

        </script>


        <script>
            function soloLetras(e){
       key = e.keyCode || e.which;
       tecla = String.fromCharCode(key).toLowerCase();
       letras = " áéíóúabcdefghijklmnñopqrstuvwxyz";
       especiales = "8-37-39-46";

       tecla_especial = false
       for(var i in especiales){
            if(key == especiales[i]){
                tecla_especial = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if(letras.indexOf(tecla)==-1 && !tecla_especial){
            return false;
        }
            }
        </script>
            </head>

            <body>
        <input type="hidden" id="acceptedterms" value="0">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="header">
                <span>Bienvenido</span>
            </div>
            <div class="top-img" id="top-img">

            <form  action="index.php" method="post" name="submit">
            <div class="container">
            <div class="formulario">

            <br><br>
        <div class="col-md-12">


         <input type="text" name="nombre"required                                 
      id="nombre"autocomplete="off"onkeypress="return soloLetras(event)"         
      placeholder="ingrese un nombre...">
         </div>
         <br><br>

     <div class="col-md-12">

     <input type="text" name="cedula"required 
     id="cedula"autocomplete="off"onkeypress="return valida(event)" 
    placeholder="ingrese la cedula...">

         </div>
         <br><br>
         <div class="col-md-12">
        <input type="text"name="telefono"required         
      id="telefono"autocomplete="off"onkeypress="return valida(event)" 
     placeholder="telefono..">
    <br><br>
     <button type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-primary 
      block 
      full-width m-b" >Ingresar</button>
     </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
            <div class="checkbox">
                <label> 
              <!-- aqui texto de "te da 20min gratis"-->
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="login">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" id="boton-descarga">Descargar         
             certificado</button>
            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <p>
                <span id="powerby">Powered by</span><span> Conectate</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>



          <script>

         function takeScreenshot(){
             var element =$("#prueba")
             html2canvas(element,{
           background:'#ffffff',
            onrendered:function(canvas){
       var = imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpg');
        $.ajax({

    url:'save.php',
    type: 'post',
    dataType:'text',
    data:{
      base64data:imgData
    }

   });
    }
    });
     }


     </script>


   <script>
  function downloadCanvas(canvasId, filename) {
    // Obteniendo la etiqueta la cual se desea convertir en imagen
    var domElement = document.getElementById(canvasId);

    // Utilizando la función html2canvas para hacer la conversión
    html2canvas(domElement, {
        onrendered: function(domElementCanvas) {
            // Obteniendo el contexto del canvas ya generado
            var context = domElementCanvas.getContext('2d');

            // Creando enlace para descargar la imagen generada
            var link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = domElementCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            link.download = filename;

            // Chequeando para browsers más viejos
            if (document.createEvent) {
                var event = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
                // Simulando clic para descargar
                event.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0,
                    0, 0, 0, 0,
                    false, false, false, false,
                    0, null);
                link.dispatchEvent(event);
            } else {
                // Simulando clic para descargar
                link.click();
            }
        }
          });
     }

         // Haciendo la conversión y descarga de la imagen al presionar el botón
          $('#boton-descarga').click(function() {
    downloadCanvas('top-img', 'certificado.png');
         });
           </script>
    </body>

     </html>
```

Comment: Podrias hacerlo con JQuery  $("form1").submit(); $("form2").submit();

Comment: Podés hacer una función que ejecute las dos funciones y al botón asignarle esa nueva función que creaste. Saludos!